Trying to upgrade spring version from 4.3.7 RELEASE to 5.3.10 getting error
Following is the error message I received:

14:01:22.771 [main] WARN
o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception
encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 2; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
14:01:22.772 [main] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context
initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 2; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 70 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:327)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:293)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
... 81 common frames omitted 2024-05-27 14:01:22.772:WARN:oejshC.appdiscoveryAdminService:main: unavailable
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 2; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Updated the configuration class as follows :
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import({DatastoreContext.class, AclContext.class, SmartConfiguration.class})
public class AdminWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    SmartConfiguration smartConfiguration() {
        return new SmartConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        SmartConfiguration smartConfig = smartConfiguration();
        if (smartConfig.isSmartEnabled()) {
            registry.addInterceptor(smartConfig.getSmartMetricsResponseHandler());
        }
        registry.addInterceptor(new PrometheusMetricsInterceptor());
    }


    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }


    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
//        converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
//
//    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        System.out.println("configure Message: "+messageConverters);
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
}
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}

Also updated jackson-databind version to 2.9.8

Don't upgrade individual versions of Spring dependencies, update all and make sure that other dependencies yo need (like Jackson) are compatible. Please add your pom.xml or build.gradle.

The WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping method is not no-arg in 5.3.10 anymore. You will have to add the corresponding parameters to match the signature, which is now:
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(
  @Qualifier(value="mvcContentNegotiationManager") ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager,
  @Qualifier(value="mvcConversionService") FormattingConversionService conversionService,
  @Qualifier(value="mvcResourceUrlProvider") ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider)

See the 5.3.10 Javadoc for reference.
Edit:
Now you are getting an exception because of an apparently conflicting Jackson version. Try updating the jackson-databind dependency to at least 2.9.4. See, for example, this SO question.

changed signature to requestMappingHandlerMapping( @Qualifier(value="mvcContentNegotiationManager") ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager,
@Qualifier(value="mvcConversionService") FormattingConversionService conversionService,
@Qualifier(value="mvcResourceUrlProvider") ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider) getting error
creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping'  in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:

Could you update your question with the exception? The comment is hard to read and does not contain the whole stacktrace.

updated the question. Can you please check

still getting bean creation exception can you check out the question again .Thank you

Your new exception has root cause: nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider - this seems like another conflicting dependency. This time with Hibernate Validator.

yes It was dependency conflict with older version  Hibernate Validator dependency. resolved Thank you
